# Copy multiple rows of cells in excel and paste them as multiple rows in a textbox in excel

Tags: excel, textbox, copy-paste, vba

When I copy multiple rows in excel and paste them in a text box, they get pasted in a single line. Are there ways to keep the multiple lines (maybe by linking the textbox to the excel cells or something)?

Comment: Copying via VBA or copying without VBA?

Comment: If the items are stored in column A starting in row 2, you could create a formula in B2, something like `=B1&CHAR(10)&A2`, and copy it down.  The last cell in column B will have the items as separate lines, with an extra carriage return at the top, which you can delete.  It is a lot more elegant to do this in VBA, but if it is a "one-time" event, this manual process may suffice.

Comment: @user14706 That isn't how SO works.  We don't custom write solutions for people.  Instead, you should show the code you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I guess CHAR(10) is for starting a new line. What is the equivalent for starting a new paragraph?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but sometimes I use `vbCrLf`

Answer (score 0):

Although it is true, we don't just provide solutions as a rule, but I thought it was a fun puzzle, so here is an alternative vba solution:

```
Function AdjustRange(Rng As Range) As String

    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant

    For Each x In Rng.Rows
        For Each y In x.Columns
            AdjustRange = AdjustRange & y & Chr(9)
        Next y
        AdjustRange = Left(AdjustRange , Len(AdjustRange ) - 1)
        AdjustRange = AdjustRange & Chr(10)
    Next x
    AdjustRange = Left(AdjustRange , Len(AdjustRange ) - 1)

End Function
```